# SwiftUI Preview timeout for large project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, timeout, swiftui

I've been trying to preview SwiftUI files in my large iOS project and cannot get past this error `TimeoutError: Timed out waiting for a thunk to build after 30.0 seconds.`

What's interesting/confusing is that a newly created SwiftUI file with the default "Hello World" Text does successfully load the preview in the same project, however more complex SwiftUI files show the time out error even when I change the preview struct to display a Text("Hello World") view.

Has anyone else experienced this or could point in what direction I can dig to fix this timeout issue?

Comment: A good signal to break complex view on smaller parts.

Comment: These views have no problem loading previews in a separate sample project, I have modularized them to pretty small views. The same files in the larger project have an issue previewing.

Comment: When I meet issue with Preview (often, 200+ views) it helps "close Preview > clean-rebuild target > open & rebuild Preview). Preview runs entire application as context, so builds it all as well if something changed, not only previewing view.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps someone else... I ended being able to load the previews by temporarily setting the project to iOS 13 development target (normally it's iOS 12). Thankfully we'll be dropping iOS 12 soon so this won't be an issue after that.

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed it on my project after leaving it be for several days cause I couldn't figure out.

So as the log mentionned, I had to "break down" my View code in smaller chunks. First identify where in the view does the compiler complain by commenting parts of it. Then when you identified the piece of code that's causing the issue create new separate views from it and call them in place of the big chunk. From my part I had a List row made of an HStack wich contained a Text and Textfield. The compiler didn't like that at all. I just put the HStack in a new view and called it in the same place and problem solved.